# Format String to Match Specific Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to figure out how to format a string to a specific pattern.

When a user is entering their employee id number, they often get confused on what is expected from them. Because they are often told that their employee id is either a 5 digit or 4 digit number depending on when they were hired.

For example, my employee id number is `E004033` but for most of our systems, I just have to enter `4033` and the system will find me.

We are trying to add this to one of our custom pages. Basically what I want to do is format a string to always look like `E0XXXXX`

So if they enter `4033` the script will convert it to `E004033`, if they enter something like `0851` it will convert it to `E000851` or if they enter `11027` it will convert it to `E011027`

Is there a way basically add padding zeros and a leading `E` if they are missing from the users input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the user's input is an integer, then format to 6 spaces using String.Format.

```
int parsedId;
bool ok = int.TryParse(id, out parsedId);
if (ok)
{
    return String.Format("E{0:000000}", parsedId);
}
```

Comment: this actually ended up working as the best solution because my coworker pointed out to me that I forgot to include people who use a username such as `jsmith`. which is only reserved to higher ups, who are paid to much to remember their employee id numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply:

```
var formattedId = "E" + id.PadLeft(6, '0');
```

To remove an existing leading E(s)

```
var text = "E" + val.TrimStart(new[] {'E'}).PadLeft(6, '0');
```

Comment: What if they entered `E004033` wouldn't that make the string `EE004033`?

Comment: Yes, I assume there is a check for an initial well formed value.

Comment: I guess I could wrap it in an `if` statement.

Comment: I would rather have a switch statement. You could be screwed if someone uses E4033

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh Or replace the "E" with "": `"E" + id.Replace("E", "").PadLeft(6, '0');` which would also correct an incorrect number of zeros.